# checking if a file is running

Tags: windows, batch-file, errorlevel, tasklist

I am trying to monitor if a batch is running or not and if it is not the case send an email.
I am using the following code :

```
Set "MyProcess=cmd.exe"
Set "taskToMonitor=taskToMonitor"
tasklist /NH /FI  "WindowTitle eq %taskToMonitor%" 2>nul |find /i "%MyProcess%">nul
If not errorlevel 1 (Echo "%MyProcess%" est en cours d'execution) else (Powershell.exe -File  D:\tmon-agent\MonitoringAgent\Mailsend.ps1)
```

---

This is sending me a mail if the batch is not running, but also if the batch is having an error even if it is still runing, which is not what i need.

Is it possible to check if the batch is runing without checking the errorlevel ?

Thanks